# How to properly set editable checkbox inside a JTable cell in Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a JTable, where I have couple of JCheckBoxes. I am initializing JCheckBoxes and other cells values from database. My problem is, when I click on the JCheckBox to checked or unchecked, they don't do nothing.

When I clicked twice, the editable JTable cell become active and shows the value of JCheckBox which is 0 OR 1. I can edit the cell with 0 OR 1 and when I save, it saves the record and load the checkbox with edited value.

Following snippet to show how I am loading and creating JCheckBoxes:

```
class TextBoxNewCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

:::
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(

case 10: //Active
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        this.add(lblStar);
                        this.add(new JLabel(value.toString(), JLabel.LEFT));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
                        checkBox.setToolTipText("Set 0 OR 1");
                        checkBox.setEnabled(true);
                        if(value.toString().equals("1"))
                            checkBox.setSelected(true);
                        if(value.toString().equals("0"))
                            checkBox.setSelected(false);
                        this.add(checkBox);
                        break;
:::

 return this;
    }
}
```

In my renderTable method I Override following isCellEditable:

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

                  switch (row){
                      case 10: //Active
                        switch (column) {
                            case 0:
                                return false;
                            case 1:
                                return true;
                            case 2:
                                return false;
                            case 3:
                                return false;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    default:
                 return false;
                }
            }
        };
```

Here is the picture of the JTable when I double click on JCheckBoxe:

[image]

Is there anyway I can checked or unchecked the JCheckBoxes with one click? I don't wanna update JTable cell with 0 OR 1 in order to checked or unchecked. Please Help.

Cheers.

Comment: The best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I clicked twice, the editable JTable cell become active and shows the value of JCheckBox which is 0 OR 1.

If you want the default renderer/editor to be used then you should be storing `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` in the `TableModel`.

Then you also need to override the `getColumnClass()` method of the `TableModel` to return `Boolean.class`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. As you can see I am working with a table where I have to specify row and column index. getColumnClass() takes only column as parameter. Is there any working sample similar to my scenario. Thanks a bunch in advance. Cheers.

Comment: @SadequerRahman, A JTable is designed for the same data in each row. I would suggest you should not be using a JTable for the form displayed in your question. Just create a panel using JLabels, JCheckboxes, and JTextFields. Maybe you could create a JTable with 4 rows and 2 columns for your "enable data". If you really want to play with different data in the same column then this link might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216409/class-specific-renderer-component-not-called/33218124#33218124