# How to implement getColumnClass method for a column having different types of components

Tags: java, swing, jtable, columnsorting

I searched all over and every implementation returns `return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();`

But in my table one particular column contains difftent types of components like text fields, comboBoxes etc. How can I get the column class of a particulr row of that specific column?

Note: I can't hard code the row number because the components loaded into rows can change at diffent times

Comment: *"But in my table one particular column contains difftent types of components like text fields, comboBoxes etc"* - `JTable` isn't designed to support this, from the sounds of it, you trying to put together a property sheet of some kind - I'd recommend having a look around and seeing if you can find any other examples of a property sheet and see what they do

Comment: This example may get your started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216409/class-specific-renderer-component-not-called/33218124#33218124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getValueAt method is part of the Tablemodel which contains the data. TextFields, ComboBoxes etc are part of the rendering.

I'm not sure what you whant wo do with getValueAt().getClass() without seeing your code.

What you can do is to write your own renderer for your Class. So you can decide the rendering type depending on the content of the column and row.