# Insert a JCheckBox and JComboBox inside a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jcheckbox

I'm trying to insert a CheckBox and a ComboBox on the same column, but it's a little bit tricky, I can't seem to find a solution for rendering both at once. Can someone help me with this? I would appreciate the help.

The Jtable I'm trying to achieve is below :

[image]

Comment: It's done the same way in IntelliJ as it's done in *any* IDE - with Java code. Hence the IDE is a poor tag (it should only be used for problems with the IDE itself) and Java an excellent tag.

Comment: A JTable isn't designed to construct a pivot table like your image.  In a JTable, the subjects would be columns and the values would be rows.  What you're trying to build is called a form, consisting of alternating JLabels and JTextFields, JCheckBoxes, or JComboBoxes.  You use a [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to create a form.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216409/class-specific-renderer-component-not-called/33218124#33218124 for one approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this example will solve your problems

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * <code>CellBasedTable</code>.
 */
public class CellBasedTable extends JTable {

    private static class TableCell {

        /** Column of the cell. */
        private final int column;

        /** Row of the cell. */
        private final int row;

        /**
         * Creates cell with the given row and column.
         * 
         * @param aRow row of cell.
         * @param aColumn column of cell.
         */
        public TableCell(int aRow, int aColumn) {
            row = aRow;
            column = aColumn;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof TableCell) {
                TableCell another = (TableCell) obj;
                return row == another.row && column == another.column;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(new int[] {row, column});
        }
    }

    private final Map<TableCell, TableCellRenderer> rendererMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<TableCell, TableCellEditor> editorMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * 
     */
    public CellBasedTable() {
    }

    /**
     * @param dm
     */
    public CellBasedTable(TableModel dm) {
        super(dm);
    }

    public void setCellRenderer(int row, int column, TableCellRenderer r) {
        rendererMap.put(new TableCell(row, column), r);
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        return rendererMap.getOrDefault(new TableCell(row, column), super.getCellRenderer(row, column));
    }

    public void setCellEditor(int row, int column, TableCellEditor e) {
        editorMap.put(new TableCell(row, column), e);
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
        return editorMap.getOrDefault(new TableCell(row, column), super.getCellEditor(row, column));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(CellBasedTable::startDemo);
    }

    private static void startDemo() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] {"Subject", "Value"}, 0);
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"name", "Variable"});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Stored", Boolean.TRUE});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Stroed Arguments", "job"});
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"task", "job", "rule"});
        CellBasedTable tbl = new CellBasedTable(model);
        tbl.setCellRenderer(1, 1, tbl.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
        tbl.setCellEditor(1, 1, tbl.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
        tbl.setCellRenderer(2, 1, new ComboRenderer(combo));
        tbl.setCellEditor(2, 1, new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
        tbl.setRowHeight(24);
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("TableTest");
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(tbl));
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class ComboRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        private final JComboBox<?> combo;

        /**
         * 
         */
        public ComboRenderer(JComboBox<?> combo) {
            this.combo = combo;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            combo.setSelectedItem(value);
            combo.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            combo.setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());
            return combo;
        }
    }
}
```