# Create JList with 3 Items: Checkbox, Image and Text

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have added an image and text into a `JList`. Now I want to add a checkbox but I don't know how to make it. Can I, for example, create a new class with the 3 items: Checkbox, Image and Text?

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,    boolean cellHasFocus) 
{
    ProfItems item = (ProfItems) value;
    this.setText(item.getName());
    this.setIcon(item.getBild());       
    
    //Sample 08: Draw Background for Selected Item
    if (isSelected)
    {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    
    //Sample 09: Reset the Background for Un-Selected Item
    if (!isSelected)
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    
    //Sample 10: Draw a Border to Show Focussed Item
    if (cellHasFocus)
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE));
    }
    else
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use different components. You should let your getListCellRendererComponent return the exact component you want instead of the one you currently return (this, which is a JLabel). To speed things up, you only need one instance of each component, i.e. you can reuse the component to return.

Comment: A JList is not designed to display components that you can interact with. Try using a single column JTable. You can use an editor to interact with the check box. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216409/class-specific-renderer-component-not-called/33218124#33218124 for an example to get you started.

Comment: @Just another Java programmer thank you very much for your answer, now i want to know how can i create that component which contains a image, checkbox und text??? can you give me please an example

Comment: @ily No, I don't have an example. But try to follow my directions: create one instance of each component in the renderer and make sure you return for example a checkbox for row 2 etc. Once you have that upp and running, read the link provided by camickr.

Comment: @Just another Java programmer
 thank you very much my code works now
 public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
 {
      
        cbSelect.setSelected(isSelected);
        
         ProfItems item = (ProfItems) value;
        lbPerson.setIcon(item.getBild());
        
 lbPerson.setText(item.getName()); return jPanel1;
 }